# KineticJS globalCompositeOperation and android support

Tags: android, canvas, kineticjs

I tried several attempt to be able to use the `context.globalCompositeOperation` and set it to `destination-out` within KineticJS.

I made a `Kinetic.CustomShape` that inherits from `Kinetic.Rectangle` (my surface to make disappear little by little). I then used `this.sceneFunc()` in my init method to use a custom method. The idea is that depending on the user input I will draw a path that will be removed from the basic rectangle.

As in the last KineticJS lib the context given to the scene function isn't a regular context I used `context._context` to access the native object and use it to setup my so call "removal" path

```
customDrawingMethod: function (context) {
  Kinetic.Rect.prototype._sceneFunc.call(this, context);
  if ( I need to remove pieces of my rectangle) {
    var path, point, i, j;
    for each point in my path {
      point = first point;
      if (point !== undefined) {
        context.beginPath();
        context._context.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-out";
        context._context.strokeStyle= "#FC0";
        context._context.lineWidth = 25;
        context._context.lineCap = "round";
        context._context.lineJoin = "round";
        ... the actual drawing goes there...
      }
    }
  }
},
```

Everything was working fine on my desktop browser and on most emulator but... I have an issue on some Android devices (Samsung Galaxy Note for instance) and on some of the manymo emulator (https://www.manymo.com/emulators/83/connect). The issue is that on those devices my removal path is never drawn except if I remove the line `context._context.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-out";` or if simply change the `destination-out` value to something else like `xor` (which give funny results but not what I am looking for...)

Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 0):

I know it's late but may be it will be helpful for someone else.
Next solution was working for me:

```
canvas.style.opacity = 0.99;
window.setTimeout(function() {
    canvas.style.opacity = 1;
}, 0);
```

Comment: I don't have the code at hand anymore but I'll check your answer later.